# Highstock chart rangeSelector minute and day doesn't work

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to make a candle-stick chart with [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/) but I can't get the `'minute'` and `'day'` timespans to work. They're greyed out as if disabled. Here's a quote from [their documentation](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#rangeSelector).

> Defines the timespan, can be one of 'millisecond', 'second', 'minute',
> 'day', 'week', 'month', 'ytd' (year to date), 'year' and 'all'.

I've got all other types working, so it's not that I don't understand the code, I even tried replacing it with 3600000 milliseconds but the result is the same. I'm thinking maybe there's a minimum value for it to work, but I haven't found anything about that in the documentation.

Please help me figure this out.

Edit: As requested in the comments here's an example of the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/UT2tr/

Comment: Could you reproduce your example as live demo?

Comment: @SebastianBochan Sure, here: http://jsfiddle.net/UT2tr/

Comment: You need to set minRange http://jsfiddle.net/UT2tr/1/ but as I see your data is each day, not hour so for 1h you will have empty chart.

Comment: @SebastianBochan Flawless thanks! Change your comment to an answer so I got something to accept. And the data is highstock's example data. I'll fix that later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set `minRange` http://jsfiddle.net/UT2tr/1 but as I see your data is each day, not hour so for 1h you will have empty chart.

Comment: I'm using gwt-highcharts with highcharts.js 5.x and I had to use: `axis.setOption("minRange", 30*24*60*60*1000)`. I needed months, but it may be useful for someone else.